# Can the phrase "push something on someone" be used in the sense if selling something to someone they don't need?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Could you please tell me if the phrase *push something on someone* be used in the sense if selling something to someone they don't need by being slick or? For example:

> I didn't need the expensive phone,but the sales agent **pushed** it **on** me.

Are there other ways to say that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a legitimate usage of the phrase.  It implies that the sales agent was (overly) assertive and pressured you into buying the expensive phone, even though you probably would not have selected that phone otherwise.